# Apply a function from package to one column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   id  floor   room          company
0   1      1  101.0              NaN
1   2      1  102.0            繁簡轉換器    ---> need to convert 
2   3      2  201.0      缔美诗药妆皮肤管理中心
3   4      2  201.0     TT潮牌造型设计（上海）
4   5      2  202.0     TT潮牌造型设计(北京)
5   6      3    NaN            繁簡轉換器    ---> need to convert 
6   7      3  201.0              NaN
7   8      3  301.0  湖南杰牌传动科技发展有限公司
```

I need to convert `company` column from traditional chinese to simplied chinese using this [package](https://github.com/berniey/hanziconv).

I tested with string `繁簡轉換器`, it converts successfully:

```
>>> from hanziconv import HanziConv
>>> print(HanziConv.toSimplified('繁簡轉換器'))
繁简转换器
```

But as I try to apply it to `company` column:

```
from hanziconv import HanziConv
df['company'] = df['company'].apply(HanziConv.toSimplified())
```

It returns an error: `TypeError: toSimplified() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'`.

Anyone could help to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `HanziConv`, but this may be work.

`df['company'] = df['company'].astype(str).apply(HanziConv.toSimplified)`

Comment: Yes, this works if there are no `NaN`s in `company` column, otherwise, it returns `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Change `NaN` to other, empty string, like ''. Or create wrapping function which calls `HanziConv.toSimplified` only when `company` is not NaN

Comment: May I ask, if I have multiple columns to convert, `df[['company1', 'company2']].astype(str).apply(HanziConv.toSimplified)` raises an error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`.